# Images after resize not show

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This is part of my code, I'm trying to output images from XML, all things work except one, it's image resize. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, because I'm new in flash ac3 and it's hard for me to understand logic of Flash AC3.

When I launch my flash in "Addobe Flash Pro" I got resized images, but on website in flashplayer there is no images, imahes don't want to display:(

Link with flash - http://flash.leto-templates.com/flash.html

```
   var my_thumb_width: Number;
   var my_thumb_height: Number;
   var img_height: Number;
   var my_images: XMLList;
   var my_total: Number;
   var my_total_width: Number;
   var image:Bitmap; 

   function processXML(e: Event): void {
     var myXML: XML = new XML(e.target.data);

     my_thumb_width = myXML.@width;
     my_thumb_height = myXML.@height;
     my_images = myXML.image;
     my_total = my_images.length();
     my_total_width = (my_thumb_width + 10) * (my_images.length()) - stage.stageWidth;

     createContainer();
     callThumbs();
     if (my_images.length() > 6) {
       myTimer.start();
     }
   }

   ////...
   var thumb_loader = new Loader();
   var box: Product_box = new Product_box();
   thumb_loader.load(new URLRequest(thumb_url));
   thumb_loader.contentLoaderInfo.parentSandboxBridge = new Object();
   thumb_loader.contentLoaderInfo.parentSandboxBridge['url'] = thumb_url;
   var handleComplete:Function = buildHandleComplete(i);
   thumb_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleComplete );
   ////...   

   function buildHandleComplete(i:int):Function {
     return function(event:Event):void {
       thumbLoaded(event, i);
     };
   }

   function thumbLoaded(e: Event, i: Number): void {
     image = new Bitmap(e.target.content.bitmapData);
     image.width = my_thumb_width;
     image.height = 140;
     image.y = 47;
     image.x = (my_thumb_width + 10) * i;
     container_mc.addChild(image);
   }
```

Comment: Maybe your my_thumb_width variable is somehow 0. Try setting it to some number and test it

Comment: code updated. 

no, because I get it before from XML - my_thumb_width = myXML.@width;